# Printing with Mapfish straight from Google Chrome without saving to file to computer?

Tags: mapfish, chrome

I have Mapfish printing in ForestKit applicatioin. When I try to print a map, mapfish downloads the file to the downloads folder and then I can print the map.

It would be better for me if I could print straight from Google Chrome's printing preview.

Is this possible?